# present modal view on top of modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tab-bar application and i'm presenting a modal view on top of it which is the user login view if the user is not logged in.

In the login view i have a register button which should show a register view.

How can i show the register view as a `presentModalViewController` on top of the login view which is already a `presentModalViewController` on top of the tab-bar view?

**EDIT:**
i'm using this code for the tabBarController to show the login view

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

i tried the same for the Login view to show the registration view, this is what i did but did not work:

```
[self.modalViewController presentModalViewController:createAccount animated:YES];
```

Comment: I've had exactly the same situation and I went with navigation controller (register form is displayed sliding from right to left). I also wanted to try flipping modal view controller's view to display register form on "the other side" of login view.

Comment: IMO Eimantas ideas sound great concerning the user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to present `ModalViewController` on top of an `loginViewController` and you are inside the `loginViewController` you just need to call it directly on the `self` pointer.

```
[self presentModalViewController:createAccount animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE: For 6.0+**

```
[self presentModalViewController:createAccount animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to present next modal view on top of the first modal view (by calling -presentModalView... on the first modal view controller). Then simply dismiss first modal view and second one view will disappear together with the first one

Answer (score 0):

Same way as the first one, use presentModalViewController.